# arcpy.da.ListSubtypes returns empty IOError on 64bit

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.6

I'm trying to use “ListSubtypes” function in ArcGIS Python.

It works on 32bit environment (f.e. - 
Desktop), but it does not work in 64bit (f.e. - Server) and returns IOError without any information – f.e.: “IOError(u'sde_pipe.SCHEMA.feature',)”.

I am using arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management to make connection and setting it with `arcpy.env.workspace`.

Code snippet:

```
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(datatype="FeatureClass")
                for root, feature_datasets, feature_classes in walk:
                    for feature_class in feature_classes:
                        try:
                            subtypes = da.ListSubtypes(os.path.join(root, feature_class))
                        except:
                            arcpy.AddWarning("Unexpected {} error:{}".format(feature_class, sys.exc_info()[0]))
```

Comment: What parameters are you supplying to `arcpy.env.workspace`?  I think you should remove your try/except in any code you present here and while testing so that no error messages are being masked.

Comment: It does not matter if i setting workspace or not. Tried to set variable `workspace = r'c:\Temp\connection.sde'` and list subtypes by using `subtypes = arcpy.da.ListSubtypes(workspace + "/" + fc1)` or `subtypes = arcpy.da.ListSubtypes(workspace + "/" + "dbName.SCHEMA.dataSetName" + "/" + fc1)` also tried with os.path.join - still returns IOException. Removing `try/except` does not help to clarify issue.